# Input two values into a 2 by 3 matrix

Tags: c#, arrays

Im trying to input two values as a 2 by 3 matrix but keep getting the error 'string is not in the correct format', this code has worked for other problems but not now, any suggestions?

```
    int test = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] nutjob = new int[2, 3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {    
    for(int o = 0; o < 2; o++)
     {
       nutjob[o,i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Split());   
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Split` returns an array of `string`s which is incompatible with `int` parsing as you tried to do. Try pre-storing it and accessing it later, like that (values inputted to `values`, later used):

```
int test = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] nutjob = new int[2, 3];
string[] values = Console.ReadLine().Split();
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{    
    for(int o = 0; o < 2; o++)
     {
         nutjob[o, i] = int.Parse(values[i * 2 + o]);   
     }
}
```

You can alternatively get the numbers line by line, like:

```
nutjob[o, i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

If you want to input it as a matrix you might also want that one, that will input the columns, row by row:

```
int test = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[,] nutjob = new int[2, 3];
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{    
    string[] values = Console.ReadLine().Split();
    for(int o = 0; o < 2; o++)
    {
        nutjob[o, i] = int.Parse(values[o]);   
    }
}

/* 
* Input like:
* 3 4
* 5 7
* 2 6
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

`string.Split` returns an array o strings, and `int.Parse` doesn't accept array of strings, which is why you see an exception.

You just need below, but be aware of non-int input might cause an exception.

```
nutjob[o,i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:
int.Parse(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '));